# Cant print out tfrecord features

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am writing a python code to create tfrecord file which stores A and C as features, But I am having trouble to print out the A,C values from TFrecord file. Can anyone take a look at this?

```
#Writing TFrecord file
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 

writer=tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('output.tfrecord')

A=[1,3,4]
C=[1.1, 2.1, 3.1]


feature_A=tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=A))
feature_C=tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=C))

features={'A':feature_A, 'C':feature_C}

example=tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=features))



writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()


#Read TFrecord file    
import tensorflow as tf 

reader=tf.TFRecordReader()


filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
   ["output.tfrecord"])

_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

feature_set = { 'A': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
               'C': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32)
           }

features = tf.parse_single_example( serialized_example, features= feature_set )
A=features['A']
C=features['C']

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run([A,C])) # print out nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are two issues:**

---

1. FixedlenFeature has to have the size defined. So change to:

   ```
   feature_set = { 'A': tf.FixedLenFeature([3], tf.int64),
                   'C': tf.FixedLenFeature([3], tf.float32)}
   ```
2. You need to start the queues for reading the inputs, so your code should look like:

   ```
   with tf.Session() as sess:

       # for the queues
       init_op = tf.local_variables_initializer()
       sess.run(init_op)

       # Create a coordinator, launch the queue runner threads.
       coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
       threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
       try:
          for _ in range(1):
             print(sess.run([A,C]))

       except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
       # When done, ask the threads to stop.
       print('')
       finally:
          coord.request_stop()
          # Wait for threads to finish.
       coord.join(threads)
   ```

Comment: Becase the operations you have defined in your data read operations involves queues. Check https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TFRecordReader